# How do i know locations of google street view image?

Tags: google-maps

I wanna know locations (Latitude and Longitude) of google street view images around a specific location. How do i do ? (google maps api, javascript, URL)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService) (emphasis mine):

> **Directly Accessing Street View Data**
>
> **You may wish to programmatically determine the availability of Street View data**, or return information about particular panoramas, without requiring direct manipulation of a map/panorama. You may do so using the StreetViewService object, which provides an interface to the data stored in Google's Street View service.
>
> You may initiate two types of requests to the StreetViewService:
>
> `<snip>`
>
> - Request with a StreetViewLocationRequest this searches for panorama data over a given area, given a passed LatLng.

**code snippet (copied from [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service), click on the map to return the nearest StreetView panorama)**

```js
/* 
 * Click the map to set a new location for the Street View camera.
 */
var map;
var panorama;

function initMap() {
  var berkeley = {
    lat: 37.869085,
    lng: -122.254775
  };
  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));
  // Set up the map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: berkeley,
    zoom: 16,
    streetViewControl: false
  });
  // Set the initial Street View camera to the center of the map
  sv.getPanorama({
    location: berkeley,
    radius: 50
  }, processSVData);
  // Look for a nearby Street View panorama when the map is clicked. 
  // getPanoramaByLocation will return the nearest pano when the 
  // given radius is 50 meters or less.
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    sv.getPanorama({
      location: event.latLng,
      radius: 50
    }, processSVData);
  });
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: data.location.description
    });
    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: 270,
      pitch: 0
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
      // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID.
      panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: 270,
        pitch: 0
      });
      panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Street View data not found for this location.');
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
<div id="pano" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does help me. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this link out for geo location](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/GeoPlugin-Tutorial-Get-User-Location-Information-IP-Detection)
should send you in the right direction. It works on the persons IP address, so if their IP is masked or re-routed, you will not get ACCURATE longitude and latitude, but the location of their ISP